# JAVA_HOME gives me wrong value on node

Tags: java, jenkins

I have Jenkins node with the below configuration for JavaPath:

`/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java`

I wrote a simple Jenkins job which prints JAVA_HOME:

`#!/bin/ksh
echo "JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}"
echo $PATH`
for some reason, the output I'm getting is:

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31`
why it doesn't use the value which used to load the node? I don't have such Java reference on the node.
BTW, it's Jenkins container, not VM

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is meant to point to the directory containing `bin/java`. That seems correct.

Comment: But there is no Java 1.8.0_31 on this node. So from where Jenkins takes this value?

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't notice the difference in version number.

Comment: Is there a `JAVA_HOME` configured under `Mange Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> JDK`? You may have to click on `JDK installations` to be able to see what's configured there.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the value jdk.1.8.0_31 is present there. When I changed it to 131, it print that version. So it means I should mention here all the Java versions I'm using in all of my Jenkins nodes? And in case of different versions which being used by nodes, how does it knows which `JAVA_HOME` to print? Per what was defined in JavaPath of the node?

Comment: @Unforgettable631, can you pbilish it as an answer?

Comment: @arielma, good questions. I think you can simply add more java versions and with pipeline script you are in control to load / use any version you defined in your stage. Yes I can publish it as an answer, but I do not know the answer of your second question, we only use 1 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a `JAVA_HOME` configured under `Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> JDK`. If you provide multiple, you need to specify the Java version that will be used by the build execution.

You can also use existing Java available on the system as well.

For example we have this in pipeline script to identify & print defined tools. `tool name` is the `Name` of the JDK defined in `Global Tool Configuration`:

```
def jdktool = tool name: 'JDK-1.8.0', type: 'hudson.model.JDK'
env.JAVA_HOME = "${jdktool}"
```